# Returning multiple values using multiple matching criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, filtering, matching

I have a table with three columns. The column headers are thus: Customer, Event, and Owner. I want to enter a "Customer" and "Event" value in reference cells and have the formula return a list of all the "Owner" values that match the Customer and Event criteria.

I have a formula that filters on one criteria and returns a list of all matches (F1 is my reference cell):

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$6,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$6=$F$1,ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROW(1:1)),1)),"",INDEX($C$1:$C$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$F$1,ROW($A$2:$A$6)),ROW(1:1))
```

I have a formula that filters on two criteria, but only returns the first match (J1 and J2 are my reference cells):

```
=INDEX(C2:C6,MATCH(1,(A2:A6=J1)*(B2:B6=J2),0),1)
```

I need help combining the two formulas so that I can both filter on two criteria and return all the matches in a list. I tried adding a second criterion to the IF statement nested in the SMALL function of the first formula, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you use Excel's built in data filter?

Comment: Your first formula is *surprising*. Are you sure it is correct? I think you'll get more help if you show the data.

Comment: @xidgel: Yes, I could use the data filter for the second criteria, but I was hoping to streamline the processes with the formula.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your interest. @Excel Hero: I pulled the first formula from a tutorial site, but if you have a better formula in mind I'm all ears. Here is my data: Customer column: North, North, North, South Event column: Upgrade, Upgrade, Patch, Upgrade Owner column: Ben, Josh, Kate, Tim I'd like to enter "North" & "Upgrade" and get a list back with "Ben" & "Josh". Let me know if there is a better way to share data. I tried a screenshot, but I don't have the points yet to post images. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to know what you need without seeing the data, but please give this a go.

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$1:C$11,SMALL(IF((A$2:A$11=J$1)*(B$2:B$11=J$2),ROW(A$2:A$11)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

After confirming the formula you can then copy it downward.

Comment: When I enter the formula, it returns the value for the cell below the one that is expected. So, if the expected result is in cell C2, the formula will return the value for C3.

Comment: What row does your data start in?

Comment: Row 2. Row 1 has the column headers. I just increased the range for the index and now it is pulling the correct cell value.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I copy the formula down it returns blank cells instead of the next match in the list.

Comment: @W_New The nature of this website makes it tough to diagnose what's happening. Could you send me the file? I'm certain I can sort it quickly. My email address is: daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: Sent. Let me know if you need anything else. I really appreciate the assistance.